# The word teratogenies = "little monsters"?

Tags: meaning

In the audio book "Million Dollar Vocabulary", the word teratogenies is defined as little monsters. There is even an example which uses the word to affectionately describe small children. However, I could not find any examples on the web of this usage. In fact, the only usage I could find is of the clinical nature. 
Could anyone confirm this alternative usage of the word? I would not want to use this word improperly given its clinical meaning.

http://wordinfo.info/unit/2114

http://www.chemistryexplained.com/St-Te/Teratogen.html

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. But even a negative result is admissible if given with an attributed link.

Comment: **terato-** a combining form meaning “monster,” “malformation”: teratology.  TFD: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/terato-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've identified, this word has a generally medical usage in reference to:

> the production or induction of malformations or monstrosities, especially of a developing embryo or foetus.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/teratogeny))

However, the older and rarer definition of the word is from the word **teratogenesis**:

> noun
>   biology, pathology
>   **the creation of monsters**

([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/teratogenesis))

It appears that it is synonymous with teratogenesis and so is the process of creating a monster not the end result

Perhaps you are looking for [**teratoma**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/teratoma) which appears to be the result of teratogenesis, although this is a grisly medical term and not the sort of thing one would call a child.

Having looked at the original text it seems the author does indeed mean *teratogenies* but, since [Google Books can find no instances](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=teratogenies&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) of the word being used and a google search returns very little, I am inclined to believe the author may have presumed it to be a noun along the lines of *progeny*.

Despite this all, a company has been set up called [Teratogenies](https://twitter.com/teratogenies) using the definition of 'little monsters'. They may have used the original book mentioned by the OP or gotten it from another dictionary, in which case this answer may be wrong.

Comment: One might be tempted to use the word to refer to misbehaving toddlers, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's a clinical/medical/biological word, and not about behavior.

Comment: Yeah, having looked at definitions it's not exactly a nice word

Comment: I will purge this word from my lexicon. So much for my Million Dollar Vocabulary.

Comment: @PaulP Do you have a reference for the audiobook? If it is modern then they may just have found an obscure usage my searching didn't. (Also bit of a rep whore move but you can upvote answers you approve of)

Comment: Million Dollar Vocabulary, by Dr. J. Michael Bennett with Paul R. Scheele. First edition 1999. The companion booklet just defines teratogenies as "little monsters" and makes no mention to medical definition. I don't have the ability to upvote answers yet.

Comment: Yeah I've found an online copy (of dubious copyright infringement) but there are no citations or such, I'm going to email the bloke and see if he has any citations. EDIT: Scrap that, he's dead. We may never know but it seems to me that he mistook teratogeny (and thus the plural teratogenies) to be a noun as in progeny

Comment: I wouldn't accept my answer yet though, I've found a play group in New York who actually use this as their group name, if they have got it from another dictionary this may indeed be a real word.

Comment: See the comments at OP.